# How do i transfer linux from usb to new hdd?

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

My old laptop stopped reading the hard drive. In bios it said there wasnt one. I replaced it. Now it shows the disk in bios.

I dowloaded linux cinnamon onto a usb. Now. I can get the laptop to run linux from the usb. Everything works great. 
I thought i properly formatted the new drive and then copied linus to it . added the boot driver. Changed the boot order back to the hdd first . but it wont boot linux from the hdd. If i take the usb out it doesn't boot any OS.

Help?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Cinnamon Mint, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Linux is actually a kernel (used by my samsung galaxy phone with it's Android desktop on top), and Cinnamon is a desktop (GUI that sits on top), neither of those are actually an OS (though Linux is often used as a lazy way of referring to all GNU/Linux OSes). Please be specific with details (why are you asking here? https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

`dd` can do this.

First, plug your USB and HDD into another Linux computer;

If your USB is `/dev/sdc`, and your HDD is `/dev/sdd`, you can use this command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc/ of=/dev/sdd
```

(I am using loop device to make example, so my device name is `/dev/loopX`.)

The output is like this:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/loop26 of=/dev/loop27
1953125+0 records in
1953125+0 records out
1000000000 bytes (1.0 GB, 954 MiB) copied, 214.348 s, 4.7 MB/s
```